# Automatic and secure file transfer over two servers

Tags: networking, backup, scp

the problem is how to automatically transfer backups from server A to server B in the best possible way in terms of security?

Here is what comes to my mind:

- authorize server A pub key to access server B
- create user on server B only for backups
- run ssh-agent on server A, enter password manually after restart
- automatically copy files with scp from server A to server B

but if bad person gets access to server A, he will basically have access to server B also. So I have to restrict server B user? How can I do that, and is this the best way of doing this whole backup over network?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

- Do not allow server A to have implied `ssh` access to server B, nor allow server B to have implied `ssh` access to server A. Different passwords. No certificate-based logins. No trust.
- Set up `rsync` as a dæmon on server A such that it offers read only access to the backups, and only from server B. Not over `ssh`, but directly.
- Have server B copy the backups periodically with `rsync` from server A. (Not `rsync` over `ssh`, but using the `rsync` transport protocol)
- Use a VPN or something like `stunnel` to protect `rsync` traffic between server A and server B.

Answer (score 0):

<s>you almost have it. user on server B must be given `/bin/false` as shell,</s> this will forbid interactive login from server A <s>(but file on server B can still be fetched or deleted).</s>

Edit:

- using `/bin/false` as a shell forbid copying
- using `/usr/sbin/nologin` also (his account is currently not available.)

A more complex solution would involve `vsftp` (not `ftps`), but this require ssl certificates.

Comment: rather than `/bin/false` I'd recommend `/bin/nologin`, which gives a message if you try to login as them. I wasn't aware `scp` worked without a login, I thought it opened an SSH connection and would get kicked out.

Comment: Okay, but with nologin user will be able to download files maybe? Something like `scp remoteUser@remoteserver:/etc/shadow .`

Comment: nologin and false forbid scp in either way. on a side note, you can't read /etc:shadow unless you are root.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a `cronjob` using `scp` to copy files.

Write a shellscript `backupToServer.sh`, which tars your files-to-backup and then puts them on the server with `scp /path/to/backup/tar user@server:/path/where/backup/is/stored`. make usage of [ssh-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116454/using-ssh-keys-with-scp-and-ssh).

You can use `date` or similar tools to name your backup correctly.

With `crontab -e` you add a new `cronjob`. Take a look at the time settings of `crontab`, they are rather trivial but look weird on first sight.